# Google Places Type for german subway stations

Tags: google-places-api

Hej out there,

I have a small problem with the Google Places API and the defined types. I want to get all subway stations of German cities. In Germany you call them U-Bahn (underground tram) and S-Bahn (mostly provided by German Railway). Unfortunately the Places API returns for the Types subway_station and train_station only the spots for the German Railway. The subway isn't returned at all.

Does anyone know how to get these types of spots out of the places api?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We used OpenStreet Map for that. There you can filter the POI with railway attributes: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/DE:Key:railway

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I just found out that you can use type= light_rail_station.

I hope this helps other searchers with the same question.